# unable to loop through a block of code in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Book {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String args[]){
    Book b = new Book();
    System.out.println("********* Library Management System *********");
    b.addBooks();

}

public Book() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void addBooks(){
    int x;
    int y =0;
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to add new book, 2 to View and 3 to exit: ");
    x = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    HashSet<Books> Library = new HashSet<Books>();

        if(x == 1){
            do {

                System.out.println("Enter the name of the book: ");
                String tempTitle = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter name of the Author: ");
                String tempAuthor = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter year of publishing the book: ");
                int tempYear = input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter the Price: ");
                double tempPrice = input.nextDouble();


                Library.add(new Books(tempTitle, tempAuthor,  tempYear, tempPrice));



                System.out.println("Following details added to the database: ");

                Iterator itr=Library.iterator();  
                while(itr.hasNext()){  
                    Books b=(Books)itr.next();  
                    System.out.println("\n Title: " + b.title + " \n Author: "+b.author + "\n Publish Year: " +b.publishYear + "Price: " + b.price);  
                }  


                System.out.println("Do you want to add another book? 1. Yes 2. No");
                y = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();
            } while (y == 1);




    } else if (x == 2){

        Iterator itr=Library.iterator();  
        while(itr.hasNext()){  
            Books b=(Books)itr.next();  
            System.out.println("\n Title: " + b.title + " \n Author: "+b.author + "\n Publish Year: " +b.publishYear + "Price: " + b.price);  


        } 


    }
}
```

I am making library/book store program to learn the basics.
The problem that i am stuck with now is, 
After adding a book I want through addBooks() method, the program asks user whether they want to add another book or not. If user replies with YES i.e., 1 then it loops through the same code again.
But if user enters NO i.e., 2 the program stops after going to the main class.
I want to again ask a user the same three options whcih were asked before:
"**Enter 1 to add new book, 2 to View and 3 to exit:**"
and when user selects 2, they get all the details they added just now. and if they select 1, they again get a chance to add new books. How do i loop that part again ?

Comment: try **do while** loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your loop back a level - this will also give you cleaner code.  In pseudo-code, it will look like this.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    boolean doLoop = true;
    while (doLoop) {
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                addBook();
                break;
            case 2:
                listBooks();
                break;
            case 3:
                doLoop = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This won't help.. I want to get an option of list book after user has added books, without terminating the program. In this way I can either choose 1 or 2 or 3. But not 1 and then 2 if I want to view after adding.

Comment: Re-read the loop. The program will only exit when `3` is entered.  Otherwise, it will keep looping and you can add books or list books as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Books {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String title;
String author;
int publishYear;
double price;

public Books(String tempTitle, String tempAuthor, int tempYear, double tempPrice) {
    title = tempTitle;
    author = tempAuthor;
    publishYear = tempYear;
    price = tempPrice;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Books b = new Books();
    System.out.println("********* Library Management System *********");
    b.addBooks();

}

public Books() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void addBooks() {
    int x;
    int y = 0;


    HashSet<Books> Library = new HashSet<Books>();


    do {
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to add new book, 2 to View and 3 to exit: ");
        x = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        if (x == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the book: ");
            String tempTitle = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter name of the Author: ");
            String tempAuthor = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter year of publishing the book: ");
            int tempYear = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter the Price: ");
            double tempPrice = input.nextDouble();


            Library.add(new Books(tempTitle, tempAuthor, tempYear, tempPrice));


            System.out.println("Following details added to the database: ");

            Iterator itr = Library.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Books b = (Books) itr.next();
                System.out.println("\n Title: " + b.title + " \n Author: " + b.author + "\n Publish Year: " + b.publishYear + "Price: " + b.price);
            }
        } else if (x == 2) {

            Iterator itr = Library.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Books b = (Books) itr.next();
                System.out.println("\n Title: " + b.title + " \n Author: " + b.author + "\n Publish Year: " + b.publishYear + "Price: " + b.price);

            }
        }
    }while (x == 1 || x == 2) ;
}
```

}

This code does your needs with minimal changes.

I choose to use switch with enum instead of if else blocks. which is more easy to read and maintain as well.